# DownloadManager security of files

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

App 1:
I download a file with the `DownloadManager`

App 2:
I ask the `DownloadManager` for all downloads. I get only my own initiated, not the one from `App 1`.

Files are downloaded have a `Uri`: `content://downloads/my_downloads/id`

From 'App 2': I cannot set the `ImageUri` of a `ImageView` with this `Content Uri`. (I get a `FileNotFoundException`)

Now my question is:
If I open the `Android Downloads App` and click on the image downloaded from `App 1`. I can view it with any picture viewer on my system. Why not from with `App 2`?

Is this because of the use of `Intent` (`Action_VIEW`)? Or am I missing something?

**Edit:**

Apparently you can get the file using `content://downloads/all_downloads/<some_id>` from any other app.
Is there a way to restrict apps to access this file? So only the app who initiated the download can open it?

I'm using:

```
Request lRequest = new Request(Uri.parse(lDownloadUrl));
lRequest.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
lRequest.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);

DownloadManager lDownloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); 
long lEnqueueId = lDownloadManager.enqueue(lRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloading content is different thing than viewing content. Therefore the fact that downloading of file X was initiated by application A does NOT mean application A is able to view it. If you want your app to be used to display it, you should add `<intent-filter>` so application A could be shown on list of applicable viewers. If you want your app to be explicit viewer, you have to use some tricks like using unique file extension (and match that extension in your `<intent-filter>`.

**EDIT**

If you peek at DownloadManager sources then you notice that access to download related fields are restricted to the owner. Therefore application A can see only these downloads it has started by itself and nothing else and the same for application B (and it is irrelevant that finally, once downloaded to i.e. SDCard destination, these files are "world readable"). This also explains why application B cannot try to reach application A's downloads by using content provider - there's simply no downloads you try to refer to that are owned by application B (these are application B's). So finally, if you want to "share" downloads you have to pass download related data to application B any other way than using DownloadManager (i.e. fill Bundle with all the data and pass it to B).

Comment: I want to know why I cannot get access to downloaded files initiated from other apps. While other apps, for example picture view, can.